# Unable to scrape a certain field from a webpage within another subroutine

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, subroutine

I've created a macro to scrape some fields from a [webpage](https://www.yumm.ca/en/recipe/ginger-mushroombeef-meatballs-1) and the script is doing fine. I've parsed three fields from that site.

When I define all the fields within a single subroutine, the script works flawlessly. However, it fails miserably when I scrape the description from another subroutine. The error the script throws is `object required` pointing at this line `oDesc.innerText` in second subroutine. It seems to me that it happens because of the `HTML` variable which might be passed otherwise within the parameters.

```
Sub FetchRecipeInfo()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.yumm.ca/en/recipe/ginger-mushroombeef-meatballs-1"
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, R&, ws As Worksheet, oImage As Object
    Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
    
    R = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "Get", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36"
        .send
        HTML.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    ws.Cells(R, 1) = HTML.querySelector(".recipe-info > h1").innerText
    Set oImage = HTML.querySelector(".recipe-visual")
    If Not oImage Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 2) = Split(Split(oImage.Style.backgroundImage, "(")(1), ")")(0)
    End If
    
    FetchTheRest R, HTML
End Sub

Sub FetchTheRest(R As Long, HTML As Object)
    Dim oDesc As Object
    
    Set oDesc = HTML.querySelector(".recipe-info > p")
    If Not oDesc Is Nothing Then
        ws.Cells(R, 3) = oDesc.innerText
    End If
End Sub
```

> How can I do the rest of the scraping in another subroutine, as in `FetchTheRest()` in this case?

Comment: `ws` is not know in your subroutine (and if you would use `Option Explicit` the compiler would tell you so). Either pass it as parameter also or declare it as global variable. Btw: you should declare the parameter `HTML` with the correct type (`HTMLDocument`), no need to declare it as `Object`.

Comment: Yes, you are very right @FunThomas. That did fix the issue. If I wanted to pass `Http`, what would be the correct type of declaration If I used `Dim Http as object` and `set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")` in the first subroutine.? Is it `Http` as object? Would be glad to accept your answer if you post one. Thanks a trillion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error comes from the fact that the variable `ws` is not known in the subroutine. Using `Option Explicit` reveals this immediately. You can solve this by either passing the worksheet also as parameter or declare it as global.

When you declare a parameter, use the correct type. Your variable `HTML` is declared as `HTMLDocument`, and your subroutine expects a `HTMLDocument`. Yes, a `HTMLDocument` *is* an object, but a Workbook, a Range, a FileScriptObject and thousand other things are also Objects. When you declare the parameter type as `Object`, the compiler cannot check if the call of the subroutine is correct and you can find the error only at runtime.

Compare the two declararions:

```
Sub FetchTheRest(ws as Object, row As Long, HTML As Object)
Sub FetchTheRest(ws as Worksheet, row As Long, HTML As HTMLDocument)
```

When you call the Sub using `FetchTheRest ws, R, HTML` everything is fine (not matter which of the two declarations you use). However, when you mix up the parameters by mistake and write `FetchTheRest HTML, R, ws`, the compiler can immediately tell you that there is a problem with the call when you declare the types correctly.

When you declare them as objects, the compiler cannot see this: `ws` and `HTML` both are objects, to that fits. You will get a runtime error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method) when you access one of the objects, e.g. at the line `HTML.querySelector`, and you will not understand why because you assume that `HTML` knows this method - not recognizing that despite the name, it holds a worksheet object.

Using global variables is usually not a good idea, but when your code gets more complicated and you split your tasks to analyze the HTML file into several routines, declaring the destination worksheet as global is maybe not that bad. In that case move the variable declaration of we at the top of the code, before your first subroutine starts

```
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet  ' Now, ws is known in all routines of this module

Sub FetchRecipeInfo()
    Const URL$ = "https://www.yumm.ca/en/recipe/ginger-mushroombeef-meatballs-1"
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, R&, oImage As Object 
    (...)
End Sub
```

Comment: In addition to your explanations FunThomas, I would like to point out the difference between `early binding` and `late binding` https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/10855/early-binding-vs-late-binding Furthermore, I am an advocate of rejecting global variables. They do not serve the better readability of the code. The opposite is the case. In addition, they prevent the possibility of simply reusing code. VBA tempts you to use global variables. In other languages, this takes its toll.

Comment: @Zwenn Thanks for the link. I agree with you about to avoid globals. There are a few cases, however, where you need to pass kind of global objects to every subroutine (a worksheet, a ADO-Connection, a FileSystemObject), resulting in a unnecessary long list of parameters needed.Usually in such cases I use a wrapper function to implement a kind of singleton, but that leads to far when answering such a question

Comment: Yes, that's right. I've also had situations like this with user forms and turning off events in events. But it's nothing complicated here and everyone should always think about how best to structure the code. I started with C. If you use global variables in C, your right hand will be cut off ;-) That is my experience.